# PHPUnit mock abstract parent method

Tags: php, phpunit

i have to test class add_Hook

```
class add_Hook extends Hooks_base
```

i tried to  create a mock of hooks_base like this:

```
>  $this->oHookBaseMock = $this->getMock(
>                        'Hooks_base',
>                         array('get_database','get_arguments'),
>                         array(null,'null') //this are the parameters for the constructor
>      );


$this->hook->expects($this->any())
      ->method('get_database')
      ->will( $this->returnValue(true)
      );

      $this->hook->expects($this->any())
      ->method('get_arguments')
      ->will( $this->returnValue($arraySImpleXmlObject)
      );
```

and doing something like this :

```
 $hook = new add_Hook($this->hook)
```

And now my problem is that when i run the test it steels ask me for the 2 parameters  of the parent class (hooks_base)

the constructor is something like this

```
public function __construct($parameter_1, $parameter_2) {
    $this->_param1 = $parameter_1;
    $this->_param2 = $parameter_2;
}
```

i dont' know how to disable the constructor of the parent class and if i do it.

Comment: `add_hook` have a
 `private function init(){
 $db = $this->get_database;
 $arguments = $this->get_arguments;
}`
and yes i'm passing the two parameters there but i don't know why it is not recognizing them

Answer (score 0):

I simply create an instance of the abstract class in my test. $Object = new ABSTRACT_CLASS() and have no code in the definition of the methods that need defined as I do not intend to test the abstract method.

```
class TestAbstractInput extends AbstractInput
{
    public ImplementAbstractFunction()
    {    // Purposely empty so nothing happens. This would be defined in normal class extending AbstractInput
    }
    ...
}

class AbstractInputTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->TestClassObject = new TestAbstractInput();
    }

    public function test_isValid()
    { 
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->TestClassObject->isValid);
    }
}
```

This way the individual methods may be tested. Then I test the normal class that usually extends the abstract class to test the functions that were implemented in that class.

```
class InputTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->TestClassObject = new AbstractInput();
    }

    // Parent function should still work
    public function test_isValid()
    { 
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->TestClassObject->isValid);
    }

    public function test_ImplementAbstractFunction()
    {
        $this->assertTrue($this->AbstractFunction());
        ...
    }
}
```

**EDIT** There is also the built in getMockForAbstractClass() which may work directly for you if you are using a new enough version.  You can also instruct Mocks to not run the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "mock" the parent class of your class.  You could create a mock of your class and replace the parent methods that you are wanting to replace.

```
$add_hook = $this->getMock('add_Hook', 
                            //This will mock these methods only and leave the rest untouched provided the class is able to be loaded.
                            array('get_database','get_arguments'),
                            array(param1, param2));
$this->hook->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get_database')
  ->will( $this->returnValue(true)
  );

$this->hook->expects($this->any())
  ->method('get_arguments')
  ->will( $this->returnValue($arraySImpleXmlObject)
  );
```

Your attempt was to somehow inject the parent into class.  The class is an instance of the parent so you can't "mock" it without mocking the class itself.

In my opinion, this is not a good practice.  You are testing the implementation of your class rather than testing the behavior of your class.  Your test should rather check what your method does rather than how it does it.  What is that 'get_database' and 'get_arguments' do?  Perhaps you should be passing an instance of 'Hooks_base' into your class rather than extending it.

From what you have posted my test would look like:

```
public function testInit() {
     $param1 = <what ever the argument needs to be>;
     $param2 = <something else>;

     $addHook = new add_Hook($param1, $param2);

     $this->assertInstanceOf('Hooks_base', $addHook); //I would probably have this in a constructor test

     $addHook->init();

    //Assertions for what init() does
}
```